# Create Database trigger for custom ChangeTable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm trying to create a database trigger in SQL Server 2008 for a `tblCustomer` table. I need it to add a new row into the `tblChanges` table every time there is an insert, update, or delete within the `tblCustomer` table.

Specifically, I need it to insert the `CustomerId (PK)` that was changed, the `dateTime` that it the changed occurred, and the type of change (insert, update, delete).

I've got something along these lines so far but can't figure out the rest:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON tblCustomer

   DECLARE log_action varchar(30)
BEGIN

   IF INSERTING THEN
      log_action := 'I';
   ELSEIF UPDATING THEN
      log_action := 'U';
   ELSEIF DELETEING THEN
      log_action := 'D';
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('undefined');
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO tblChanges(ChanedPK, ChangedTime, ChangedType) 
   VALUES ...
```

I'm unsure if any of the above SQL is correct as I haven't tried running it yet and my knowledge of SQL is limited. Any help completing the code and correcting errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_trigger AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON tblCustomer
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE log_action varchar(30)

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
      SET log_action = 'INSERT'

   IF EXISTS NOT (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
      SET log_action = 'DELETE'

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
      SET log_action = 'UPDATE'

   -- Your other code goes here


END
```

Maybe you should read up un T-SQL and DML triggers in SQL Server first. MSDN and many other sites provide excellent examples on how to go about things.

Comment: Alright this works fine but i also need it to insert the current date and time aswell as the PK of the row that was altered. Any help?

Comment: okay i got the dateTime fine. its just GETDATE(). But I'm still having trouble finding the pk

Comment: SQL Server exposes the changes to a table through two virtual tables called inserted and deleted. They contain all the changed data.